# Fourier Transforms for characteristic functions

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm curious to understand how to compute the fourier transform for the following characteristic function $\chi_{[-1,1]^n}$?

I have only been able to get this far:

$\mathcal{F}\chi_{[-1,1]^n}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{[-1,1]^{n}}(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx$.

How do i proceed further? A bit confused on how the limits of the integral will change?

Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate by $\chi_{[-1,1]^n}$, what do you mean. In other words what is the expression (functional form) for $\chi_{[-1,1]^n}$? Is $\chi_{[-1,1]^n}$ some sort of random variable?

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Function which is 1 on $[-1,1]^n$ and $0$ elsewhere, and the OP meant $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}$

Comment: @reuns for your comments on my answer yesterday, see http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/indefinite_binary_Buell.pdf  That was at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514387/do-all-numbers-of-the-form-sqrtn-have-a-periodic-continued-fraction-in-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your formula $$\mathcal{F}\chi_{[-1,1]^n}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{[-1,1]^{n}}(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx$$should be $$\mathcal{F}\chi_{[-1,1]^n}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{[-1,1]^{n}}(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi\cdot x}dx$$(in your version you have the exponential of a *vector*.) Noting that $$e^{-2\pi i\xi\cdot x}=\prod_{k=1}^ne^{-2\pi  i \xi_kx_k}$$you see the whole thing reduces to $$\int_{-1}^1\dots\int_{-1}^1\prod_{k=1}^ne^{-2\pi i \xi_kx_k}\,dx_1\dots dx_n;$$you can find that integral by just calculus.