# Properties of Continued fractions of $\sqrt n$

Tags: number-theory, radicals, continued-fractions

I got to know from [this Brilliant article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/quadratic-diophantine-equations-pells-equation/) (no pun intended) that the continued fraction expansion expression of $\sqrt n$ is of the form $[a_0,\overline{a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_k}]$ for integers $a_i$ where

1. $a_0=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ and $a_k=2a_0$
2. $a_1,a_2\dots ,a_{k-1}$ is a palindrome, i.e., $a_i=a_{k-i}$

Unfortunately, these properties were presented without proof, and a quick google search didn't yield much. [A suggested question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3514387/943723) seems to be similar to a part of my question, although the answers seem to use too advanced machineries for me to understand.

I would like to have simple proofs or intuitive explanations to understand why these beautiful patters hold. [This table](https://planetmath.org/tableofcontinuedfractionsofsqrtnfor1n102) listing some continued fractions may be helpful. [This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221205104/http://web.math.princeton.edu/mathlab/jr02fall/Periodicity/mariusjp.pdf) suggested by mathcounterexamples.net is quite informative.

Comment: [This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221205104/http://web.math.princeton.edu/mathlab/jr02fall/Periodicity/mariusjp.pdf) on Period of the Continued Fraction of $\sqrt n$ may help.

Comment: Sayan Dutta, you can see the reason experimentally by taking square root of a number. Have you ever tried?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thanks for the link. It was quite informative!

Comment: @sirous do you mean "changing square roots into continued fractions" or do you really mean taking the square root? I haven't done either though, but I do have tables of both. Also, to be honest, I don't think I remember the algorithm of taking square root of a number anymore :|

Comment: There are proofs in the textbook of Niven/Zuckerman/Montgomery, for example.

Comment: Many intro Number Theory texts cover this. They all require some amount of machinery.

Comment: @SayanDutta, I give an example for converting square root to continuous fraction.Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I give an example fo converting the square root to continuous fraction:

We want to find $\sqrt{41}$. The greatest perfect square less than $41$ is $36=6^2$ , so we may write:

$\sqrt{41}\approx 6 +\frac 1 x$

We have:

$\frac 1 x=\sqrt {41}-6\Rightarrow x=\frac 1{\sqrt{41}-6}\space\space\space\space(1)$

Multiplying numerator and denominator be conjugate $\sqrt {41}+6$ we get:

$x=\frac {\sqrt{41}+6} 5$

$\sqrt{41}+6>10 \Rightarrow x>2$

So we may write:

$x=2+\frac 1y=\frac{\sqrt{41}+6}5\Rightarrow \frac 1y=\frac{\sqrt{41}-4}5\Rightarrow y=\frac 5{\sqrt{41}-4}$

Multiplying numerator and denominator be conjugate $\sqrt {41}+4$ we get:

$y=\frac {\sqrt{41}+4}5>2$

Suppose:

$\frac 1y=2+\frac1z$

We have:

$\frac 1z=\frac{\sqrt{41}+4}5-2=\frac{\sqrt{41}-6}5$

$\Rightarrow z=\frac 5{\sqrt{41}-6}$

Multiplying numerator and denominator be conjugate $\sqrt {41}+6$ we get:

$z=\sqrt {41}+6>12$

Let $z=12+\frac 1u$, we can write:

$\frac 1 u=\sqrt {41}+6-12=\sqrt{41}-6\space\space\space\space(2)$

Comparing relation (2) with (1) we find that $u=x$, s0 our continuous fraction is:

$$\sqrt {41}\approx 6+\frac1 {2+\frac1{2+\frac1{12+\frac 1{2+\frac1{...}}}}}$$

Or $\sqrt {41}\approx(6, 2, 2 ,12, 2, 2, 12, ...)$

Now we convert one part of this to ordinary fraction:

$2+\frac 1{12}=\frac {25}{12}: \frac 1{\frac{25}{12}}=\frac {12}{25} $

$2+\frac{12}{25}=\frac{62}{25}: \frac 1{\frac{62}{25}}=\frac {25}{62}$

finally :

$\sqrt{41}\approx [6+\frac{25}{62}=\frac{397}{62}]\approx 6.403$

Comment: The second to last equation sign should be an approximately-equal sign ($\sqrt{41}$ is irrational).

Comment: $Alex, I do not get what you mean.

Comment: "$\sqrt{41}=6+\frac{25}{62}$" is false: the RHS is rational, the LHS is irrational. The "$=$" should be "$\approx$".

Comment: @Alex, You are right, I corrected that.

Comment: Kind of *okayish* explanation (+1). What about the other properties though?